# Why I cannot paste images from Snagit to Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I am using SnagIt to copy images, but when I paste in Gmail the image does not show. What to do?

I tried this solution described here: http://www.itcentralpoint.com/fix-snagit-correctly-paste-images-gmail but it doesn't help. It is for previous versions of Snagit, and now it is not working any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that it is impossible to copy images from SnagIt when they have a transparent background. It happens in some effects (for example drop shadow).

To fix it go to editor settings, in the file menu:

[image: http://snag.gy/aTnjp.jpg]

Then disable image transparency:

[image: screen shot of setting]

It solved the issue for me.